# add [and] + [or ] to search filter for a foreach generated list

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, foreach, filtering

So I already have a search filter in place but now I want it to have the ability to `combine` search phrases. Below is the code that generates a list on page.

```
<div class="sortable2">
  <ul class="connectedSortable links loadfiles" id="loadfiles">
    <?php
      foreach ($result as $value) {
        list($classname, $origin, $name) = explode('_', $value);
        $classname = trim($classname, '[]');
        $origin    = trim($origin, '[]');
        $name      = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        echo "<li class='audiofile " . $name . " " . $classname . "' id='" . $value . "'>".
                "<a class='btn_clone fa fa-clone' aria-hidden='true' id='' onclick='repeat(event)' title='Clone'>&nbsp;</a>".
                "<a class='btn_addto fa fa-arrow-up' aria-hidden='true' id='' onclick='addto(event)' title='Add to playlist'>&nbsp;</a>".
                "<a class='btn_removefrom fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true' id='' onclick='removefrom(event)' title='Remove element'>&nbsp;</a>".
                "<span class='audioclass'>" . $classname . "</span>".
                "<a href='" . $directoryname . "/" . $value . "' target='_blank'>".
                  "<img src='images/avatars/" . $classname . ".jpg'>".
                  "<div class='audiotext'>".
                    "<span class='audiotitle'>" . $name . "</span>".
                    "<span class='audioorigin'>" . $origin .  "</span>".
                  "</div>".
                "</a>".
              "</li>";
      }
    ?>
  </ul>

</div>
```

This list basically generates blocks like:

```
frank
hello how are you
link to audio file

william
i am fine
link to audio file

frank
what?
link to audio file
```

The filtering is done by this code

```
$('#global_filter').keyup(function() {
    var col_name = $(this).attr('class');
    var search_val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.' + col_name).closest('#loadfiles > li').css('display', 'none');
    $('.' + col_name).each(function() {
        var val = $(this).text();
        console.log($(this).text(), 'text');
        if(val.toLowerCase().indexOf(search_val) >= 0) {
            $(this).closest('#loadfiles > li').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```

which works together with

```
<div class="input">
  <h4>Search field</h4>
  <div class="all_all" id="filter_global">
    <div align="left"><input type="text" name="global_filter" id="global_filter" class="audiofile"></div>
    <div align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="global_regex"  id="global_regex" ></div>
    <div align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="global_smart"  id="global_smart"  checked></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Question

How can I change the filter to allow for multiple search phrases with `[AND]` and maybe also `[OR]` if possible. So the user can type in for instance:

`frank [and] hello`

and this will then return

```
frank
hello how are you
link to audio file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this project appears to have not been updated in quite some time, you can probably utilize parts of it to work for your needs: https://github.com/bloomtime/boolean-expression-js

```
$('#global_filter').keyup(function() {

    // Init
    var col_name = $(this).attr('class');
    var search_val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    // Setup boolean expression
    var parsed = new Expression(search_val);

    $('.' + col_name).closest('#loadfiles > li').css('display', 'none');
    $('.' + col_name).each(function() {
        var val = $(this).text();
        if(parsed.test(val) == true) {
            $(this).closest('#loadfiles > li').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});
```

It utilizes [ReParse](https://github.com/weaver/ReParse) behind the scenes to be able to split your search on pre-defined grammar and then test for matching.

## Edit

---

If you are really trying to keep it super simple, it may not be extremely flexible, but you could try this approach. This basically gives the ability to search using `[AND]` or using `[OR]` but not both. Could probably use some refactoring as I just quickly whipped it up.

```
$('#global_filter').keyup(function() {

    // Init
    var col_name = $(this).attr('class');
    var search_val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var columns = $('.' + col_name);

    // If doing a boolean AND
    if (search_val.toLowerCase().indexOf('[and]') >= 0) {
        // Get search parts
        var parts = search_val.split('[and]');
        $(columns).each(function(columnIndex, column) {
            var val = $(column).text();
            var matched = true;
            $(parts).each(function(partIndex, part) {
                // Since AND is inclusive, failing to match should assume this column is a non-match
                if (val.toLowerCase().indexOf(part.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
                    matched = false;
                    // Break early
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (matched) {
                $(column).closest('#loadfiles > li').css('display', 'block');
            }
        });
    }

    // If doing a boolean OR
    else if (search_val.toLowerCase().indexOf('[or]') >= 0) {
        // Get search parts
        var parts = search_val.split('[or]');
        $(columns).each(function(columnIndex, column) {
            var val = $(column).text();
            var matched = false;
            $(parts).each(function(partIndex, part) {
                // With OR, if ANY of the parts match then it is a match
                if (val.toLowerCase().indexOf(part.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                    matched = true;
                    // Break early
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (matched) {
                $(column).closest('#loadfiles > li').css('display', 'block');
            }
        });
    } else {
        var val = $(this).text();
        if(val.toLowerCase().indexOf(search_val) >= 0) {
            $(column).closest('#loadfiles > li').css('display', 'block');
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I was more looking for a way to have it in the already present code and without loading yet another library or js file.

Comment: The problem is tokenizing strings and doing boolean matching on those tokens is fairly complex and isn't a small snippet of code really. That being said, let me see if I can add a "hack" of sorts you might try.

Comment: That would be really cool. Appreciate the help you are giving and suggestions. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried your Edit. And sadly it ain't working and it does not show a error. I tried typing in one word, and the [AND], and the [OR] but by all three nothing happens. Is it correct that I replace your code with the already present one.

Comment: Oops, I left "[AND]" inside the "[OR]" section. Also I just made it an else/if conditional so only one runs. This is all off the top of my head, you will probably have to do your own debugging -- its just to get you in a direction.

Comment: Sadly it always wants to do the else. And in there it returns a error called: columns not defined. Not sure what to do now. Thinking of going with the include file `expression.js` but the code you gave for that is that everything I need to use or is there more. If there is more could you change your answer so everything is in it. Thank you very much for both the edit and the include instructions.